# Cartesian on NULL arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, cartesian

I need a cartesian product of 6 arrays - the catch is that at any time upto 5 arrays could be null. It works great when all arrays are populated but bombs when any of the arrays are null

my arrays are something like this

```
MatrixArray_1[0] = 1
MatrixArray_1[1] = 2

MatrixArray_2[0] = null
MatrixArray_2[1] = null

MatrixArray_n[0] = 2
MatrixArray_n[1] = 2
```

etc.

I am using this code currently...derived from 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq.aspx

```
var product1 =  from first in MatrixArray_1
                from second in MatrixArray_2
                from third in MatrixArray_3
                from fourth in MatrixArray_4
                from fifth in MatrixArray_5
                from sixth in MatrixArray_6
                select new[] { first, second, third, fourth, fifth, sixth };
            string[][] myCombos_linq = product1.ToArray();
```

I have tried putting `MatrixArray_n where first != null` but that stops at the first null array and does not read thru all the remaining arrays so my return array is always 0 rows even though array1 and array 3 are populated.

Change of code/logic anything is appreciated at this point in time!
TIA

Comment: Logically, what do you expect to happen when one or more of the arrays are null?

Comment: Have you tried replacing the null arrays with empty arrays?

Comment: I do not want the null values to be included in the output

Comment: @user1139748 a null array is not the same thing as an array containing null values.  But if, for example, `MatrixArray_1` is null, then what value would you expect in the `first` property?

Comment: So to clarify if arrays three to six were empty you want effectively `select new[] {first, second}`? ie the outputted object is of a different form...

Comment: @PaulSasik replacing the null arrays with the empty array will result in no results, because just as `x * 0` yields `0`, so a cartesian product including a sequence with zero elements yields a sequence with zero elements.

Comment: @PaulSasik - I did use empty arrays but it returns null in the output so the first cartesian row returned is 1,null,2

Comment: You might be able to create a loop that goes over an array of arrays (your six inputs) and then if it is null or empty ditches that array  and otherwise does the cartesian product and then repeats. I can't think of any way you can do it without explicit null checks on each one though since as phoog points out trying to use an empty set in any way is going to just blank out all your results.

Comment: What is the type of `MatrixArray_N`?  Are they `int?[]`?

Comment: @Chris - I am trying out the suggestions - will keep u updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Eric's approach is to use an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>`, you must be doing something like this:

Eric's code:

```
static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> CartesianProduct<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sequences) 
{ 
  IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> emptyProduct = new[] { Enumerable.Empty<T>() }; 
  return sequences.Aggregate( 
    emptyProduct, 
    (accumulator, sequence) => 
      from accseq in accumulator 
      from item in sequence 
      select accseq.Concat(new[] {item})); 
}
```

Call site:

```
var sequences = new int?[][] { MatrixArray_1, MatrixArray_2, ..., MatrixArray_6 };
var cartesianSequence = sequences.CartesianProduct();
```

Change the call site:

```
var cartesianSequence = sequences.Where(a => a.Any(e => e != null)).CartesianProduct();
```

The Where call will exclude sequences where all elements are null.

To exclude null arrays as well as arrays containing only null values:

```
var cartesianSequence = sequences.Where(a => a != null && a.Any(e => e != null)).CartesianProduct();
```

Or, with query comprehension:

```
var filteredSequences = 
    from sequence in sequences
    where sequence != null && sequence.Any(e => e != null)
    select sequence
var cartesianSequence = filteredSequences.CartesianProduct();
```

**EDIT**

Another possibility is that you want to exclude null elements of each sequence, even if some elements are non-null:

```
var filteredSequences = 
    from sequence in sequences
    where sequence != null && sequence.Any(e => e != null)
    select (from v in sequence where v.HasValue select s)
var cartesianSequence = filteredSequences.CartesianProduct();
```

OR

```
var cartesianSequence = sequences
    .Where(s => s != null && s.Any(e => e != null))
    .Select(s => s.Where(v => v != null))
    .CartesianProduct();
```

But it's hard to know exactly what to advise since we don't know what you're doing with the result.

Comment: I was just thinking that the best way to do this would be if the MatrixArrays were in an enumerable allowing you to easily remove the ones you don't want before processing. I think I was slowly getting around to basically what Eric ended up with on that link. I only actually looked at the link when I saw this answer and saw your code was very different from the OP. :)

Answer (score 1):

Am I understanding correctly that you want to exclude any of `first`, `second`, etc. if they are `null`? That's easy:

Just add

```
select new [] { first, second, third, fourth, fifth, sixth }.Where(x => x != null)
```

to your query.

Or is that you want to exclude the entire sextuple if any of `first`, `second`, etc. are `null`? That's easy too. Just add

```
where new [] { first, second, third, fourth, fifth, sixth }.All(x => x != null)
```

to your query. You can even use `let` so you're not creating the array twice.

Answer (score 0):

By definition (and I am quoting from the previously mentioned Eric Lippert [blog](http://ericlippert.com/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq/)).
"The Cartesian product of two sequences S1 and S2 is the sequence of all possible two-element sequences where the first element is from S1 and the second element is from S2."

If you generalize the definition it would be:

The Cartesian product of any n sequences S1, S2,...Sn is the sequence of all possible n-element sequences **where the first element is from S1** and the second element is from S2 and the N element is from Sn

Note that the first element should ALWAYS be from the first element.

If you are filtering out null values of the first array that means that the whole entery would be missing, the filtered out enterys looks like this:

> (null, x2,...xn)

Here is a complete example:

> array1 = {null, 1, 2}
> array2 = {A}
>
> The Cartesian product of array1 & array2 = { {null, A}, {1, A}, {2, A}
> }

Now, let's apply the filter where First != null.

> The Cartesian product of array1 & array2 = {{1, A}, {2, A}}

Say that we changed the value of array1 to:

> array1 now = {null, null}
>
> The Cartesian product of array1 & array2 with the filter = {}

The result is empty set. In order to have a cartesian product, you have to have an entery from each array. Your question could be adjusted to address this fact.